# What is wrong with my render method here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing an example app over here to get my head around React but one of my simpler components is throwing an error that I can't seem to track.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
>   it's defined in. Check the render method of `ContactListItem`.

Here's the code for the ContactListItem component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ListGroupItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class ContactListItem extends Component {
    render() {
        const { contact } = this.props;
        return (
            <ListGroupItem>
                <Link to={'/contact/${contact.id'}>
                    <h4>{contact.name}</h4>
                </Link>
            </ListGroupItem>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactListItem;
```

It's a pretty simple class. Nothing sticks out to me as problematic. For completion's sake, here's the parent component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ContactActions from '../actions/ContactActions';
import ContactStore from '../stores/ContactStore';
import ContactListItem from './ContactListItem';

function getContactListItem(contact) {
    return (
        <ContactListItem key={contact.id} contact={contact} />
    );
}

class ContactsComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            contacts: []
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        ContactStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        ContactActions.receiveContacts()
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        ContactStore.removeChangeListener(this.onChange);
    }

    onChange() {
        this.setState({
            contacts: ContactStore.getContacts()
        });
    }

    render() {
        let contactListItems;

        if ( this.state.contacts ) {
            contactListItems = this.state.contacts.map(contact => getContactListItem(contact));
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <ListGroup>
                    {contactListItems}
                </ListGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactsComponent;
```

Comment: Have you tried it with a non-empty `contacts` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error in `ContactListItem#render()` because `Link` is undefined. As of React Router v4, `<Link />` is no longer a part of the [`react-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router), but a part of the [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) package. Changing this should fix your problem:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: That did fix it. Thank you! The way React-Router has changed between the publication of these tutorials and now is killing me. Every time I run into a road block like this it's always the same answer "React Router doesn't work like that anymore". Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link),
 use

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`
```

unlike `react-router` which used to work earlier.

But `react-router-dom` comes with:

- HashRouter
- BrowserRouter
- MemoryRouter
- Prompt
- NavLink
- StaticRouter, etc.

You might benefit from tree-shaking a lot, on using

```
import Link from 'react-router-dom/Link';
```

if all the above stuffs are not needed in your app.